# Security profiles in Docker (docker build --security-opt)

Tags: security, docker, docker-build

I'm trying to build a docker image for centos:7 that restricts system commands which any user (including root) can execute inside a docker machine. My intention is that I want to build an docker image with security profile that I need and then use that as my base image to build other application images thereby inheriting security profile from the base image. Is this doable? Am I missing something?
Here is a sample security profile I'm testing:

```
{
        "defaultAction" : "SCMP_ACT_ALLOW",
        "syscalls": [
        {
        "name": "mkdir",
        "action": "SCMP_ACT_ERRNO"
        },
        {
        "name": "chown",
        "action":"SCMP_ACT_ERRNO"
        }
        ]
}
```

When i run:

```
docker build -t test . --security-opt seccomp:policy.json
```

It throws an error :

```
Error response from daemon: The daemon on this platform does not support setting security options on build
```

Thoughts on how to get past this or other approaches I could use?

Answer (score 1):

From Github...

**"Docker engine does not support the parameter "--security-opt seccomp=" when executing command "docker build"**

> @cason you can supply a custom default profile to the daemon.
>   `--secomp-profile /path/to/profile.json'

https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/34454#issuecomment-321135510

Comment: How would I use this parameter during build? It didn't seens to be a docker build parameter